# Derive correct URLs from HTML JS src tag

Tags: python-3.x, url, html-parsing

I'm parsing HTML websites using Python3's *html.parser* to search for all included JavaScript files. For that I loop through all *script* tags and retrieve the content of the *src* attribute.

The challenge is to build the correct URLs. The src attribute may contain a full-qualified URL like *https://example.com/jsfile.js* but it may also be that it just contains a relative path. In these cases I have to set the scheme (http or https) and domain / network location manually.

As I could not come up with a reliably-working solution: does anybody have an idea how I can do this in Python3.5?

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

urllib.parse.urljoin to get full urls

If its full path it will return as it is, and if its relative it will return full path.

here is an example:[image]